# Multiline equation with specific indentation style

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I have a multiline equation of the following type:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x,y) & =a\\
& =b\\
& +c\\
& +d.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But the output I would like to have is as follows:

```
 f(x,y) = a
        = b
          + c
          + d
```

That is, the lines *continuing* the sum shall have additional indentation, that is, the +'s shall not be directly below the "=". Whatever I tried didn't work as intended. Do you have any suggestions as of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple solution with `\phantom` command:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x,y) & =a\\
       & =b\\
       &\phantom{=}\, +c\\
       &\phantom{=}\, +d.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

gives:

[image]

This is the better looking alignment, in my opinion. Anyway, you can adjust it with spacing commands. For example, the following code

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x,y) & =a\\
       & =b\\
       &\phantom{=}\, +c\\
       &\quad +d\\
       &\phantom{=}\; +e.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

produces:

[image]

As you can see, a little spacing is added in consecutive lines.

Comment: I typically use `\quad` with is roughly of the size of `\phantom{=}`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks for your comment, I've added some more info in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can just "flip around" the use of the alignment character `&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x,y) & =a \\
    & =b \\
    & +c \\
    & +d.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x,y) ={}& a\\
    ={}& b \\
    & {}+c \\
    & {}+d.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The additional empty groups `{}` ensure the correct spacing around binary operators/relations. If you wish the alignment of the `+`s to be more aligned with the RHS of the equations above, you could also use:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    f(x,y) ={}& a\\
    ={}& b \\
    & \mskip-\medmuskip +c \\
    & \mskip-\medmuskip +d.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which removes the space around the binary operator `+`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While @Werner's answer works well for your particular case, if you actually need two (or more) explicit lines of alignment, you can use the `alignedat` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    f(x) & ={} && a \\
        & ={} && b \\
        & && + c \\
        & && + d.
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(I do not include the picture, since the result is exactly the same as in Werner's answer; the trick with `\mskip`/`\medmuskip` can be applied as well).

Answer (score 1):

There are various answers here that explain how to achieve this manually, but I think that it is worth mentioning the [`breqn`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn?lang=en) package, which attempts to automatically break long display math equations. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
  f(x,y) = 2x( x^2 + 2x + 1) + 2y(y^2 + 2y + 1) 
  + 2z(z^2 + 2z + 1).
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Note that the `+` is automatically aligned at the right location. The `breqn` package is somewhat experimental. Do read its documentation for caveats; but when it works, it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to add space in front, and using just `align*`. You could repeat it multiple times as you need.

```
 \begin{align*}
    f(x,y) & = a\\
    & = b\\
    & \, + c\\
    & \; + d\\
    & \: + e\\
    & \  + f \\
    &\quad + g\\
    &\qquad + g
 \end{align*}
```

[image]